# Gogs on Nginx in subdomain is not working

Tags: nginx, gogs

I have some Problems with gogs and nginx in my local-Network.

everytime i write "domainname" i mean the hostname of the server

I have little Server running with Openmediavault on it (for NAS) and i also will run some Stuff like gogs. It is running, but only on the URL "http:domainname:3000"
I will have gogs available under git.domainname or gogs.domainname

I have tried so many things, but noting is working.
I have add a config on available Site /enabled-sites (symlink):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name git.domainname;

  location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}
```

In my gogs Configuration, i have the following Server-Section:

```
[server]
PROTOCOL     = http
DOMAIN       = domainname
HTTP_PORT    = 3000
ROOT_URL     = http://domainname:%(HTTP_PORT)s/
DISABLE_SSH  = false
SSH_PORT     = 22
START_SSH_SERVER    = false
OFFLINE_MODE    = true
```

I have not very much experience in Nginx. so I hope anyone can help me to get this work. Also i hope i get more experience to get work other services in a generic Way to work in subdomain

when any Information is missing to help me, please let me know

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Show the relevant entries in the `nginx` access and error log. Use `curl -i` to see what your website is returning. At the moment your question is too broad to answer.

Comment: access.log is empty and error.log shows not relevant data. curl -i shows Could not resolve host

Comment: Ok, that means the the problem occurs  **before** anything you have posted here. "Could not resolve host" implies there is no DNS record for your new sub-domain.

Comment: what is the Way to setup a subdomain in local network ?

Comment: How did you set up "domainname"?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, because the setup of this Machine was before around 2 Years. I setup this Machine with Openmediavault (so it's debian-based)